# UDP broadcast send not working in UWP

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I tried to create an UDP send and listen application with UWP based on [this source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DatagramSocket/cs/Scenario5_MulticastAndBroadcast.xaml.cs).

It should work like this:

- Listen on port 8080 for messages
- Send message to the broadcast address
- Receive messages from another UDP server that listens for messages sent to the broadcast

I have the `Listen` and `Send` methods.

**Constructor**

```
public MainViewModel()
{
   Listen();
   Send();
}
```

**Listen**

```
private async void Listen()
    {
      listenerSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      listenerSocket.MessageReceived += (x, y) =>
      {
        var a = "2";
      };
      await listenerSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("8080");
    }
```

**Send**

```
private async void Send()
    {
      IOutputStream outputStream;
      string localIPString = GetLocalIp();
      IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Parse(localIPString);
      string subnetMaskString = "255.0.0.0";
      IPAddress subnetIP = IPAddress.Parse(subnetMaskString); 
      HostName remoteHostname = new HostName(GetBroadcastAddress(localIP, subnetIP).ToString());
      outputStream = await listenerSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(remoteHostname, "8080");      
      DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
      writer.WriteString(localIPString);
      await writer.StoreAsync();
    }
```

It seems that the *broadcast* sending is not working.

I have another program (written in Java) that also sends a message to the broadcast address, and *this listener* receives the messages sent back from the broadcast.

What should I set to make the sending work?

Comment: Can you please post your `GetBroadcastAddress(localIP, subnetIP)` code ? I think the problem may be here, I tested your code, but changed to use the localaddress, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

i didn't see any `GetBroadcastAddress(localIP, subnetIP)` code here. But as I see, your problem may be with this code:

```
HostName remoteHostname = new HostName(GetBroadcastAddress(localIP, subnetIP).ToString());
```

I changed it to:

```
    HostName remoteHostname = new HostName(localIP.ToString());
    outputStream = await listenerSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(remoteHostname, port);
```

Here is my sample code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    DatagramSocket listenerSocket = null;
    const string port = "8080";
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Listen();
        Send();
    }


private async void Listen()
{
    listenerSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    //listenerSocket.MessageReceived += (x, y) =>
    //{
    //    var a = "2";
    //};
    listenerSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
    await listenerSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
}

private async void Send()
{
    IOutputStream outputStream;
    string localIPString = GetLocalIp();
    IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Parse(localIPString);
    string subnetMaskString = "255.0.0.0";
    IPAddress subnetIP = IPAddress.Parse(subnetMaskString);
    HostName remoteHostname = new HostName(localIP.ToString());
    outputStream = await listenerSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(remoteHostname, port);

    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream))
    {
        writer.WriteString("aaaa");
        await writer.StoreAsync();
    }


}

//private object GetBroadcastAddress(IPAddress localIP, IPAddress subnetIP)
//{
//    throw new NotImplementedException();
//}

async void MessageReceived (DatagramSocket socket, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader();
    uint len = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
    string msg = reader.ReadString(len);

    string remoteHost = args.RemoteAddress.DisplayName;
    reader.Dispose();

    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        text.Text = msg;
    });

}

private string GetLocalIp()
{
   ...
}

}
```